# Completion Routine of IRP sometimes in IRQL 2 sometimes IRQL 0

Tags: windows, kernel, driver

Within a Thread in IRQL 0 the completion routine, triggered from an IRP, for a WskSendTo call is sometimes in IRQL 2 and sometimes in IRQL 0. This seems mighty strange to me. Does anyone know if this is normal behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal behavior.

Completion Routines may be called directly in the call to the routine or from any other context.

See the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms795852.aspx) for a description of IoCompletion routines.

Comment: @Christopher: I owe you a beer. 

Because of this behaviour every context must be allocated in non-paged memory. And as IoAllocateMdl has no flag to achieve this one has to call MmBuildMdlForNonPagedPool afterwards.